# How to move docker volume to disk location?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-container

I have a [MySQL docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) running in a docker container on Ubuntu VPS. I bring up MySQL using the `docker-compose up -d` command via the following `docker-composer.yml` file

```
version: "3"
services:

    mysql_server:
        image: mysql:8.0.21
        restart: always
        container_name: mysql_server
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: db_name
            MYSQL_USER: db_username
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: db_password
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
        volumes:
            - mysql_server_data:/var/lib/mysql
            - /mysql/files/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
```

I am having some performance issues and would like to do the following in attempt to improve performance.

1. I want the data in the `mysql_server_data` volume to be mounted on `/mysql/data` without losing any data as this instance in running in production.
2. I also want to mount the MySQL config file on `/mysql/files` so I can change the instance configuration to increase performance.

**Questions**

How can change the data location of a the volume from `mysql_server_data` to `/mysql/data`?

Also, how can I mount MySQL's config file on `/mysql/files/conf.d` to allow me to update the settings?

I tried to mount config file like this

```
        volumes:
            - /mysql/files/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
```

But that created a directory `/mysql/files/conf.d` with no config file.

Answer (score 3):

To move the data:
Shutdown the container with docker-compose down, then on the local file system, copy the data from mysql_server_data  to /mysql/data. Then change the compose file to reflect the new location. Finally restart the container with docker-compose up.

To mount the config files, as per the docker hub documentation for MySQL, If /my/custom/config-file.cnf is the path and name of your custom configuration file, the your volume map is:

/my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d

Note that mapping the volume to the container does not bring the data from your container to you local, but the other way around. So if you want to have the file in the container, you must first create it on your local.

Comment: I finally was able to attempt this. I copied the data using this command `cp -a /var/lib/docker/volumes/root_mysql_server_data/. ./mysql/volume`. Then in the `docker-compose.yml` file, I changed `- mysql_server_data:/var/lib/mysql` to `- /mysql/volume:/var/lib/mysql`. Then I executed `docker-compose down` then `docker-compose up -d`.. but that did not work. I got the following error from MySQL `--initializing specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.` The designed data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all the files that the server added to it.

Comment: I just tried it with a small test DB and it worked fine for me. Keep in mind that you should shutdown the image first to ensure no data is lost. so compose down -> copy -> compose up. Notice that it may indeed warn that the data is already there, which is expected (data is already there after all), but at least for me that is just a warning and the DB worked just fine..

Answer (score 0):

Use the trick suggested by Docker maintainer [Sebastiaan van Stijn](https://github.com/thaJeztah) at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31417 to send the tar over stdout:

```
docker run --rm -v vol_name:/vol_path img_name sh -c 'tar -cOzf - /vol_path' > volume-export.tgz
```